# Get URL of current post but not the page number

Tags: templates, pagination

Instead of using a plugin, I am manually adding buttons into my template file, like so:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php get_permalink() ?>" data-width="100" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

However, when I have a multipage post, I don't want that the like button links to `/the/post/2` on the second page, but to `/the/post` (i.e. the first page). I have been looking through the docs but there doesn't seem to be a way to get permalink of the post, without the page number. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your code works as expected because you are not printing the URL of the post. Note that [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) returns the permalink of current post inside a loop but doesn't print it like [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink). So, you should use `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` or `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`.